# Can I set ldap_use_admin_to_bind to false when using devise_ldap_authenticatable for AD?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I am using devise_ldap_authenticatable to authenticate user against Active Directory. The
authentication works successfully.
However, there is one issue.
Currently, the devise.rb is configured to use ldap_use_admin_to_bind = true, 
and ldap.yml is configured to have admin_user and admin_password set properly.

If any one of these 3 settings is changed/removed, user authentication failed.

I wonder how I can omit these fields because I don't want to save the AD administrator
password to the file. Any idea ?

I am thinking that the user's supplied username and password is enough for ldap to check
if it can bind to AD or not.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The same technic as with database.yml:

- does not store it in vcs
- it supose to be on server with secure permtions in shared/config
- create link after deploy

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. I discovered that changing "attribute: sAMAccountName" to "attribute: cn" in my ldap.yml file allowed me to set config.ldap_use_admin_to_bind = false in devise.rb, and user auth would work (without having admin un/pw set). Not sure if this will work for you or not.